# Why do I get a "value cannot be null" error when adding a Caliburn.Micro bootstrapper to App.xaml as a resource

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, caliburn.micro

After creating a class `Bootstrapper` derived from `PhoneBootstrapper`, I've added it to

```
<Application
    ....
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:....">

  <Application.Resources>
      <local:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
      <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper"/>
  </Application.Resources>
```

which immediately gives me an error of "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: rootFrame" while in the XAML editor for `App.xaml`.

Strangely enough, if you look at the output window after a build, there are 0 errors.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a known issue. http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/307

The workaround is to add

```
if (Execute.InDesignMode)
    return;
```

at the start of `protected override void Configure()` in your bootstrapper-derived class.